# calculate 6 month change in TED spread

Tags: spread

I have a basic question if someone could help me out how would I calculate    the 6 month change in TED spread. I have a monthly time series of TED spreads.

Answer (score 1):

```
TED spread 6mo chg = TED Spread{t} - TED Spread{t-6}, t := month
```